# Simple LED Blinking project - PIC16F877A microController problem

Tags: microcontroller, led, blink, pic16f877a

[image: schematic of circuit]

I am trying to simply blink an led light using pic16f877a microcontroller. softwares i am using are, MPLABX IDE, MPLAB IPE and XC8 compiler. I use Pickit 3.5 programmer. My head-aching question is, i have no errors when downloading the .hex to microcontroller in the IPE programme (it says "Programming complete" and when verify --"Verify complete"), but the led not even light up. but when downloading the programme, i can see the **led randomly blinks or keep lit for sometime**, then when done programming, it goes off.

**I've made sure,**

-led working
-connections are good
-pic is new (although tried using it for three or four times)

**I'm not sure**
-whether i'm using something called "signal diode" correctly as stated in here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVQ4tj-D8jM. i am using IN4007 diode (to connect its cathode to the MCLR of pickit's output...

**Code:**

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = HS        // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR disabled)
#pragma config LVP = ON        // Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit 
Serial Programming Enable bit (RB3/PGM pin has PGM function; low-voltage 
programming enabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit 
(Data EEPROM code protection off)
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits 
(Write protection off; all program memory may be written to by EECON control)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit 
(Code protection off)

void main(void)
{
    TRISB=0b00000000;
    PORTBbits.RB0=1;
    return;
}
```

**UPDATED Code: (WORKING - only during 'connecting' period of pickit to MPLAB IPE software)**

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 20000000
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// CONFIG
#pragma config FOSC = HS        // Oscillator Selection bits (HS oscillator)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF      // Brown-out Reset Enable bit (BOR disabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF         // Low-Voltage (Single-Supply) In-Circuit 
Serial Programming Enable bit (RB3/PGM pin has PGM function; low-voltage 
programming enabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF        // Data EEPROM Memory Code Protection bit 
(Data EEPROM code protection off)
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Program Memory Write Enable bits 
(Write protection off; all program memory may be written to by EECON control)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection bit 
(Code protection off)

void main(void)
{
    TRISB=0;

    while(1)
    {
        PORTBbits.RB0=1;
        __delay_ms(50);
        PORTBbits.RB0=0;
        __delay_ms(50);

    }
}
```

**Components in my circuit breadboard,**

-pic16f877a microcontroller + base

-led

-IN4007 diode (its cathode connect to MCLR of pickit's output)

-20MHz crystal oscillator (to CLKIN and CLKOUT of pic)

-2x22pF capacitors (for oscillator)

-330R resistor (for led from pin RB0)

-10k resistor (for IN4007 diode from MCLR of pickit's output)

-0.1uF capacitor (for IN4007 diode to connect to ground)

-jumper wires

-pickit3.5 connection

**I tried using several microcontrollers like pic16f84a and pic18f452 also, following different tutorials on internet, but no luck. i really love doing this and i am not hoping to give it up.**

Anybody please help, it will relieve a big headache!
Thank you very much!**

Comment: Are you sure that the LED isn't active low? Try writing a zero. Also make sure you set the data direction register for port B (DDRB) to outputs.

Comment: I've changed the code such that RB0=1 and RB0=0, but when i measured voltage across the led, the slight voltage of about 0.05V remained constant. BTW, i am a beginner although i've done some electrical stuff back then.

Comment: @DiBosco, i've added a diagram. PS: i am not familiar with schematic designing and electronics at large. but i hope i have converted my circuit to an understandable schematic.

Comment: One thing that occurs to me (sorry this is nothing to do with the hardware) is that your software should have: while (1); instead of return; I'm not sure what your processor will do when it hits the return; statement and what state it will put the pins in.

Comment: I reckon D2 is completely unnecessary BTW.

Comment: @DiBosco MCLR is tied to a high voltage during flash programming by the debugger, the diode is recommended by microchip

Comment: You have low voltage programming enabled (#pragma config LVP = ON) but RB3 is floating, which may cause the PIC to randomly go into programming mode. Since you are not using LVP you should turn it off. Do you have a bypass capacitor (0.1uF or higher) from Vdd to Vss?

Comment: Have you set the PIC programmer options to supply power to the breadboard? Measure the Vdd (to Vss) after programming and make sure there is a proper supply voltage there. And make sure you have a 100nF to 1uF ceramic capacitor from Vdd to Vss located near the chip.  replace ***return;*** with something like ***for(;;);*** which will stop the program right at that point. The LED blinking during programming suggest something hardware-related is going on.

Comment: @BruceAbbott i turned off LVP and Also added a bypass capacitor between Vdd and Vss near pickit connectors on breadboard. Oh YESSS!!! i think i'm getting closer. i just tried setting different values for __delay_ms(500) and then i COULD SEE THE CODE IN ACTION, BUT, ONLY during the little time the pickit is connecting to the IPE programme. i think this is a minor issue, so anybody please help. (Code updated)

Comment: Have you verified your oscillator circuit? A common mistake is choosing the load capacitors incorrectly. I would recommend using the internal RC oscillator (assuming this chip has one) until you get up and running.

Comment: That's a lot of code. Consider "How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution:

- I closed MPLAB IPE completely.
- Then from project properties of MPLABX IDE, I selected the needed power and selected option to power the target from PICkit3.
- Then "made" the program.
- To run it, clicked on "Release from Reset".

IT WORKED!!! Now the LED blinks like COOL!!! Headache cured!

Comment: You can accept your own answer to indicate the correct solution to your question. Thank you for posting the solution. +1

Comment: When I get to the point where I can ask an intelligent question, I usually can find a solution. +1